# HelmetJS on Yarn Package not installing

Tags: node.js, express, yarnpkg, helmet.js

I am building a micro-service and using Yarn Package to install `helmet`/`helmetjs`. But I am receiving this error which is shown on the image below. What could be the problem?

[image: img for the error]

Comment: Helmet maintainer here. Helmet doesn't have any dependencies, so I suspect this is a dependency (or sub-dependency) of another package. Maybe try finding that dependency (`yarn why` might help) or trying to reproduce this in another project.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, your correct it is more on a dependency of another package. I just have removed my `yarn.lock` and run the `yarn add helmet`.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the `yarn.lock` and `node_modules`, and run the command `yarn install`.

The possibility of this issue is due to corrupt `node_module` and `yarn.lock`.